# C programming and calculation

Tags: c, visual-studio

Today I tried to make a calculator which converts a distance to meters, inches, etc. I have written my little program in C with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

My problem is, when I enter a number the program is calculating wrong!

PS. It's not homework, it's an exercise from "Let us C", which I'm reading ATM.

I get the following output:

> Enter values of the distance between the two cities in km's10 Meter=0
>   inch=-1064763392 feet=-2147483648 cm=1103731097 Waiting for a
>   character to be pressed from the keyboard to exit.

```
/*Just for fun Author: Anru*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int km;
    float result_met, result_inch, result_feet, result_cm;

    /*Display text*/
    printf("Enter values of the distance between the two cities in km's");
    scanf_s(&km);

        /*Formular for a simple km conversion*/

    result_met = km * 1000;
    result_inch = km * 39370; 
    result_feet = km * 3280;
    result_cm = km * 100000;

    /*Result print*/
    printf("Meter=%d\ninch=%d\nfeet=%d\ncm=%d",result_met, result_inch, result_feet, result_cm);

    printf("\nWaiting for a character to be pressed from the keyboard to exit.\n");

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not a sufficient description of what's wrong. So you get wrong output? Please elaborate. Include exact input and output.

Comment: "calculating wrong" isn't exactly descriptive. wrong **HOW**? Wrong answer? Wrong inputs? Crashes? Become sentient and takes over SkyNet?

Comment: Change `%d` --> `%f`, the rest of your code should work. Voting to close as something that is unlikely to help other visitors of the site.

Comment: Still getting the wrong following output:

`Enter values of the distance between the two cities in km's1
Meter=201326592.000000
inch=-1694498816.000000
feet=-1744830464.000000
cm=-1342177280.000000
Waiting for a character to be pressed from the keyboard to exit.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `scanf_s()` call is wrong.  The first argument is a *format string* which describes what is being read.  Your compiler should probably be issuing a warning with the current code, and if it is not, you need to increase the warning level, as heeding the compiler's warnings will save you headaches for things like this.

An appropriate call might look like:

```
scanf_s("%d", &km);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `%f` to print `float` type instead of `%d`, otherwise program will invoke undefined behavior.

```
printf("Meter=%f\ninch=%f\nfeet=%f\ncm=%f",result_met, result_inch, result_feet, result_cm);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the input reading that is wrong:

```
scanf_s(&km);
```

should be

```
scanf_s("%d",&km);
```

The value in km could be anything with the original code